Reflexive objects in the category of $G$-sets
Let $G$ be a group. Consider the category of $G$-sets, whose objects are sets $X$ with an action $G \times X \to X$ satisfying $e \cdot x = x$ and $g \cdot (h \cdot x) = (gh) \cdot x$ and whose arrows are $G$-maps, i.e. $\varphi: X \to Y$ such that $\varphi(g \cdot x) = g \cdot \varphi(x)$.
It is well known that this category is Cartesian closed. Explicitly, let $\hom(X,Y)$ be the set of $G$-maps $G \times X \to Y$. With action $(g, \varphi) \mapsto \varphi(-g,-)$, $\hom(X,Y)$ is again a $G$-set.
First question: is there any example of $G$-set $X$ such that $\hom(X,X)$ is a retract of $X$? It is standard to say that a $G$-set $X$ such that $\hom(X,X)$ is a retract of $X$ is reflexive.
(In a previous version of this question, I erroneously thought that the group $G$ itself were reflexive).
Second question: is there a way to characterise reflexive $G$-sets or $G$-sets such that $\hom(X,X) \simeq X$? I would be happy with both a categorical, "abstract nonsense" characterisation, but also with a concrete, "down to earth" one. Are there any references that point to that kind of things?

To be clear, by "reflexivity" you mean a $G$-set $X$ such that $\operatorname{hom}(X, X) \simeq X$ as $G$-sets?

Thanks for your question, I have expanded a bit.

What do you mean by $\hom(X,Y)$? If you mean the set of all functions, then it’s not true that $\hom(G,G)$ is isomorphic to $G$. But if you mean the set of $G$-set maps, then what $G$-set structure are you putting on $\hom(X,Y)$?

This answer is relevant, especially near the end.

Thanks @Jeremy, I added details.

With the definition you've given, $\hom(G,G)$ isn't isomorphic to $G$ for any nontrivial group $G$. As a $G$-set, $\hom(G,G)$ is isomorphic to the disjoint union of $|G|$ copies of $G$.

I am confused, but you are right.

The $g\cdot\varphi$ that you define in the later edit is not usually a $G$-map, as $(g\cdot\varphi)(hx)=\varphi(ghx)$, whereas $h(g\cdot\varphi)(x)=\varphi(hgx)$.

I think you've been confused by two possible meanings of $\text{Hom}$ in this context. First, we could be referring to the ordinary homomorphisms, namely the morphisms $X \to Y$ of $G$-sets. Second, we could be referring to exponential objects. Let me write these as $Y^X$ to avoid confusion. This consists of arbitrary functions together with the $G$-action given by conjugation. In any cartesian closed category, the relationship between the ordinary hom and the exponential is given by
$$\text{Hom}(X, Y) \cong \text{Hom}(1, Y^X).$$
In $G$-sets what this means is that a morphism $X \to Y$ of $G$-sets is a fixed point of $Y^X$ under the $G$-action, hence a function which is invariant under conjugation, so that checks out.
$G$ is the free $G$-set on a point, meaning we have a natural identification $\text{Hom}(G, X) \cong X$ given by evaluation at the identity, which gives $\text{Hom}(G, G) \cong G$. This is not a statement about exponential objects; in particular $G^G$ has cardinality $|G|^{|G|}$ as a set (so I don't think Jeremy Rickard's characterization of it in the comments is correct).

First question: is there any example of $G$-set $X$ such that $\hom(X,X)$ is a retract of $X$?

Only the terminal object $1$. This is because any reflexive $G$-set must in particular be a reflexive set (because the forgetful functor to sets is cartesian closed), but for a set $X$ the cardinality of $X^X$ is strictly larger than the cardinality of $X$ unless $X = 1$, so it can't be a retract unless $X = 1$.
In general it is not so easy to find reflexive objects, since the Lawvere fixed point theorem implies that they must have the fixed point property.

It is standard to say that a $G$-set $X$ such that $\hom(X,X)$ is a retract of $X$ is reflexive.

This seems a little misleading to me. I have never heard this use of the term "reflexive" before, in any context and certainly not in the context of $G$-sets (where as we've seen above it degenerates). The terminology appears to come from categorical logic.

You're right that I was wrong. I should have written "product" where I wrote "disjoint union".

Thanks for your clear answer. The terminology is indeed borrowed from categorical logic, but is inappropriate for $G$-sets as it turns out.
